# how to use font face attribute to html without using html?

Tags: html, css, web, font-face, webfonts

I am  in a condition where I cannot use spreadsheet like CSS , but I want to use font face in HTML but how can I add external fonts here only using HTML.

```
@font-face{
    font-family: diploma;
    src: url('../fonts/diploma.ttf');
}
```

here i can use src but how can i use src and Font face in HTML

Answer (score 2):

The obsolete `<font>` element allowed you to specify the name of a font which a browser will try to load from the user's system.

Support for external font files was first implemented using CSS and has never been available without CSS.

In short: You can't.

Comment: can i use @font-face in internal css?

Comment: You can use it in a `<style>` element. You cannot use it in a `style=` attribute.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping